# why does a1 remain void? Is it possible to have an event listener to return output to string?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

```
var a1 = document.getElementById("wanInt").addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.target.value)
  x = e.target.value; 
  console.log(x + "it works");
})
console.log (a1)
```

I am trying to have the output of a change in a text field return directly to a string which I can print out later.

Comment: because addEventListener does not return anything, it is undefined. What you are trying to do is not possible. What is your exact use case?

Comment: The return value of `addEventListener` is `undefined` and not, as you appear to expect, the value that the callback function you pass to it will assign to `x` when, at some point in the distant future, the user changes the value of the input.

Comment: @epascarello I have a form of about 15 fields which the user fills and each individual input is added to a variable which is then passed as template string to a `pre` string. The latter is printed in a generated text file.

Comment: how do I return a value then please? @Quentin

Comment: So read the input value when you want to use it. There should be no reason why you would listen to an event other than to validate it.

Comment: @AhmadFathy — Return it from the future? You can’t. See the duplicate.